# Upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite - MAMP 2.0.5 is not working

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp, osx-yosemite

I have recently upgraded OS X from Mavericks to Yosemite but now MAMP is not working, apache server and mysql server both are unable to start.

I am using MAMP 2.0.5 free edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache set your port to default (80)

Navigate to the mamp/library/bin folder and rename envvars to _envvars. BTW this has been resolved on the official webpage ;)